# Remove GRUB from Data HDD

Tags: ntfs

Before Ubuntu installation the drive had one NTFS partition with data. I used windows software to shrink the NTFS partition and create 2 more unformatted partitions for ubuntu installation.

At this point I made a backup of the MBR using windows.

Since then, files have been added / changed on the NTFS partition but the partitions stayed the same size and no other partition was created.

In removing GRUB so to make disk unbootable (If I just erase ubuntu system, I still get a GRUB message at boot - if the disk is 1st in queue), IS IT SAFE for my NTFS files to replace the MBR with the one I have saved???

Thanks

Comment: In your case it should work. Having a backup of the MBR is always handy, but I'd only use it as a last resort. Booting from a repair-CD and  calling `bootrec /fixmbr
` (as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/277924/75166)) is the safer method.

Comment: @MadMike, I thought that fixmbr would do for a disk of a single partition.
My backup has the info about the 3 partitions as follows:
1.NTFS partition with files as they were at the time of backup.
2.2 empty, unformatted partitions.

Comment: The fat is stored in the partition, not in the MBR right?
The question is, if overwrite the MBR with the saved one, will my changed/new files (both in ntfs and system Ubuntu partitions) be there OR will I get the disk as it were at time of MBR backup?
Thanks