# How to remove grub off laptop

Tags: boot

Someone gave me a pavilion g6 with grub on it but no hardrive so I bought a hardrive tried to install Windows 7 but every time I turn the computer on it says grub rescue error or something like that. Please help I have no experience with ubuntu. How do I get rid of it and put Windows 7 on there.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: I found [this][1] helped me previously. 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/277718/removing-grub-and-mbr

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows, but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/
They have a version for 32 or 64 bit OS.

I also believe that the Windows restore cd has a mode to fix the bootloader, I just can't remember how it is started plus you had to issue commands.  With the boot repair disk you just have to click the button.